# ~10 inch laptop that supports at least 32 GiB of RAM (or cheap and 16 GiB of RAM)?

Tags: laptop, memory

I am thinking of a new laptop, and I recognised that in the range of ~10 inch displays not so much is available anymore than about 10 years ago.

I am looking for a laptop with ~10 inch display (ca. 20..25 cm wide, ca. 15..22 cm deep), which has the ability to have 32 GiB of RAM (or 16 GiB of RAM but then is "cheap"). Thickness is less important.

I can do upgrade works on my own which do not require soldering of chips. I am very fine with used or refurbished devices. It can also be a "barebones" laptop, or an option to assemble all individual parts by myself.

It has to be a laptop-style, i.e. the keyboard-part firmly attached to the display-part, and not some "wobbly" dock.

It should have at least 2 full sized USB A ports and at least one digital display out port and wireless LAN, and the hard disk must be replaceable without soldering.

Some bonuses, not necessary: >=3 USB A ports, full size HDMI port, RJ45 LAN port, a battery that is replaceable without screwdrivers, memory upgradeable.

I know about the [Panasonic Let'sNote CF-RZ8](https://panasonic-jp.translate.goog/pc/p-db/CF-RZ8AFMQR_spec.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-GB), which can come with 16 GiB of RAM (soldered in), and the [GPD Win Max 2](https://gpd.hk/gpdwinmax2), which comes in a 32 GiB version.

The CF-RZ8 with "only" 16 GiB of RAM with still at price tag of more than 2500€ (excuding import taxes) seems too expensive for me given that I want to use it for many years and that I cannot upgrade the RAM. The GPD Win Max 2 I am reluctant about because I really did not like the keyboards of the GPD Pocket 1 and GPD P2 Max, and GPD devices are known to have poor quality mechanical manufacturing here and there.

Which other machines are out there that fulfill my requirements?

x86 architecture would be highly preferred, but not necessary.

Regards!

Comment: Can you detail a little bit why you need such a quantity of RAM? Many people believe they need much more RAM than what is really needed. In many situations, RAM can be more than compensated by a performant graphic card, a top notch SSD (with SLC or MLC) and a good processor. Is it for a RAM disk? And what is your tolerance for the screen size? Would a 12'' laptop still be suitable or too large? I simply want being sure to well understand the needs.

Comment: Are you OK to strip some of the requirements, like two USB ports, replaceable disk? Have you consider searching for "mono" block like Microsoft Surface Pro?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I need to use it on a lap, so keyboard and display part need to be connected like a laptop. If it is a tablet that docks to a keyboard in a _stiff_ connection that would also be OK. Harddisk needs to be replaceable (M.2 2280 is OK, I currently have a GPD MicroPC modified to accomodate 2280 form factor). Only one USB-A port is exceptionally OK if I really cannot find anything else.

Comment: @OuzoPower: I currently have 8 GiB, and I get out of memory situations when stitching big panoramas, opening many images in gimp, compiling some sources (especially android needs a lot of RAM), firefox sometimes ... and I want 32 instead of 16 to be save for some years. Regarding size, I really want to go back to the CF-R4 form factor. Roughly as wide as a A4 page is wide (maybe a bit wider). Currently I am at GPD microPC, I want to go larger; but I also had 12 inch devices, too large. >10 Years ago it was easy to find (by that time) decent 10" devices. Computing speed is not my main need.

Comment: Want to add that it not necessarily needs to be x86 architecture.

Comment: @GolarRamblar, about Surface - it offer touch screen so you can do good amount of work w/o keyboard. About additional disk on Surface - no, you can't even open it...

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Not an option without keyboard or a keyboard dock without _stiff_ hinge. And I need to be able to run my own GNU/Linux and I am able to do manual work to get things to work (as long as drivers exist in the mainline kernel or in maintained(!) external sources; I cannot write driver code, but I can recompile kernel).